# Linq to Entities Multiple left outer Joins in VB.NET

Tags: linq-to-entities

I am using Linq to entities which does not allow the .DefaultIfEmpty method.  I need to know how to preform the following Multiple left outer join using Linq to Entities in VB.net

```
select * from capitalrequests cr 
left outer join capitalrequestquotes crq on cr.ID = crq.CapitalRequestID 
left outer join la_vendor lv on crq.vendorid = lv.id where cr.id='84D6A08D-5D59-47F9-BF0C-F41F9F5A6FF9'
```

Comment: What is the shape of the result set you want back?

Comment: see this example to get an idea
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2772017/linq-to-entities-left-join/2772550#2772550